# Safely restricting key-based authentication for only sftp access

Tags: ssh, security, sftp, key-authentication

I can restrict a key installed into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to only allow file transfers by forcing an in-process SFTP server:

```
command="internal-sftp" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1...(the key follows)
```

However, using sftp connection it is possible to transfer a new version of `authorized_keys` to the server, with the restriction removed, new keys added and so on. Afterwards, it is possible to connect interactively.

File transfers are exceptionally dangerous due to this possibility. Is there any way to prevent this, for example, to forbid access to anything within `~/.ssh/` when using `internal-sftp`?

Comment: This user is using different keys for different purposes, not necessarily SFTP. All of them are going to be restricted, though. If you are thinking about restricting if by forcing command in sshd_config and making an SFTP-only user, that won't fit.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been my first idea. I don't know if it is possible to restrict SFTP usage in the way you want - the only thing I could imagine would be a tailored SELinux policy, but I have too little experience to figure out how to do it in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there isn't another way to get around this. At least I haven't found it with the LXC container I'm using to test it.

As root
`chattr +i .ssh/authorized_keys`

Then the user can't modify the file.

A possible other way would be change the location of authorized_keys or even make it look them up with a script. Then the user can't modify the keys ever.

Even a third option is use ssh certificates with the lockdown for command in the cert for the sftp only users and a second cert that doesn't have that lockdown.